# Typecast variable to extract of nested data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, javascript-objects

I'm receiving an array of nested objects from an API call from which I need to extract information and bundle it to be able to display it in a table. I'm using `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result))` for looping through the results. My code works fine but gives me an error on `yarn build` on the step where I'm trying to extract nested objects from the `value`. I'm currently doing this by using the dot notation as `value.property`.
Sample code :

```
const result = await HTTPService.get(`myEndpoint/v1`);
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result)) {
     name = key;
     if (value.property1) {
         myVar = value.myProperty1.subProperty1;
     }
}
```

Error: `Property 'myProperty1' does not exist on type 'value'`

`result` (response from the API call) looks something like this:

```
{
  name1: {
     myProperty1: {
         subProperty1: []
         subProperty2: {}
        }
     myProperty2: {}
  }
}
```

Comment: just want to double-check some items here, Object.entries(res). Should that be Object.entries(result)? Also, I believe you still need to access the object like result[key].property1. Could you add in the response you are getting from your request to help better as well :)

Comment: Yess, that should be result instead of res. Will update in the question.
I was using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries as reference on accessing the key and value. The response I'm getting is the result I've shared in the end.

Comment: @AakankshaSharma What are the types of `result` and `value` according to TypeScript?

Comment: `any` and `unknown` respectively. I tried to typecast `value` to my custom type, but wasn't able to get it to work @AmitBeckenstein

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the response is going to be of that shape, you could typecast it using `as` keyword. You could create a custom type of the shape of the response you get (you can probably just put `any` for  any of the sub properties you don't care about, or just completely ignore them) and typecast it using that type.

```
type MyResType = {
  name1: {
     myProperty1: {
         subProperty1: something[]
         subProperty2: {...}
        }
     myProperty2: {...}
  }
}

const result = await HTTPService.get(`myEndpoint/v1`);

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result as MyResType)) {
     name = key;
     if (value.property1) {
         myVar = value.myProperty1.subProperty1;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For TypeScript to detect that `value`'s type is the type of `name1`, you need to check `if (key === 'name1')`. In the context of this `if`, TypeScript will know that `key`'s type is `"name1"`, and then it can infer the type of `result[key]`.

```
interface Result {
  name1: {
     myProperty1: {
       subProperty1: [];
       subProperty2: {};
     };
     myProperty2: {};
  };
}

const result = await HTTPService.get(`myEndpoint/v1`) as Result;

for (const key of Object.keys(result) as Array<keyof Result>) {
  name = key;

  if (key === 'name1') {
    const typedValue = result[key];
    // works: TS knows that `typedValue`'s type is `{ myProperty1: ..., myProperty2: ... }`
    myVar = typedValue.myProperty1.subProperty1;
  }

  // doesn't work: `key`'s type in this context is `keyof Result` and not specifically `"name1"`
  const untypedValue = result[key];
  myVar = untypedValue.myProperty1.subProperty1;
  //      ~~~~~~~~~~~~ TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
});
```

See [TypeScript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQM4FcA2ZkDeAsAFDLIhwC2EAjAFyGnktUCeAClAPYAO0YNgyZkWLbACMufAUMYBtALoBuZmPKTp-KIIBMjAgF9VolsbWtOPbXoPnR98pRr7kWEAGsQ3AO4gThqSkOBD4zhCMHhBs3DBomLhgJgjcIBj4UAl4jOjYeMgAvCJO1HQGFsjsWrLCxKbiWFLWNQqKADQVGo3VOmyuRh31hoNiVc29-cNqU6LhriC4OIP2ABQA8hIAVhAIYAB0UWwYK5l5YACUyHAYyACCUFBwbAA8h7HxZwB853sw3FAAUUQAAsVitDpcCp9ihRSoVkIcTGpgHFwdFCgUigBycK0LGXOpiFJpfAANzgOCwKCKp0S8kOKgq7AAanAoPDyZSIHsxjJerQ9ppxoJaCZyIESIZzkA).

Answer (score 0):

### Using Optional Chain

You can use optional chain to avoid that type checking error.

```js
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(result as MyResType)) {
     name = key;
     if (value?.property1) {
         myVar = value.myProperty1.subProperty1;
     }
}
```

### Add Response Type

As the response from the API is unknown on side of frontend. And you could add the type checking for the response.

If you are sure about the response type, you can define it's response's type.

```js
type ResultType = {
  name1: {
     myProperty1: {
         subProperty1: Array<any>
         subProperty2: {}
     }
     myProperty2: {}
  }
}

const result = await HTTPService.get<ResultType>(`myEndpoint/v1`);
```